# Split String Using Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have a below set of string :

> *H. NGUYEN1, J. SATZ2,3,4,5, R. TURK2,3,4,5, K. CAMPBELL2,3,4,5, S. MOORE1 
> 1Pathology, 2Mol. Physiol. and Biophysics, 3Neurol., 4Intrnl.
>   Med., Univ. of Iowa, Iowa City, IA;  5Howard Hughes Med. Inst., Iowa
>   City, IA

The expected output is :

> 1)  *H. NGUYEN1, J. SATZ2,3,4,5, R. TURK2,3,4,5, K. CAMPBELL2,3,4,5, S. MOORE1
>   2)   1Pathology, 2Mol. Physiol. and Biophysics, 3Neurol., 4Intrnl. Med., Univ. of Iowa, Iowa City, IA;  5Howard Hughes Med. Inst., Iowa City,
>   IA

The above string is the author names and address combinations.
Sometimes the string contains (;) after the names end i.e. **S. MOORE1;** and sometimes not i.e. **S. MOORE1**

I tried the below Regex but its not giving expected results . Please help me as I am a learner of Regex.

> ;?[\d*]\w+

Pattern is :

> Word followed by digit followed by semicolon or space followed by
>   digit followed by words . For Ex: S. MOORE1(; Or Space)1Pathology.Need
>   to split lines as S .MOORE1 and 1Pathology
>
> Thanks

Comment: What are the rules? It looks like you only want to number lines..

Comment: You need to describe the pattern a little better if you want a useful answer.

Comment: The pattern is Name followd by digit followd by semicolon or space followed by digit followed by words . For Ex: S. MOORE1(; Or Space)1Pathology.Need to split lines as S .MOORE1 and 1Pathology.

Comment: -1, sorry: I find this question *very* unclear. I don't understand what your input "set of string" is, I don't understand what your expected output is, and I don't understand what connection your described pattern has with the input and expected output. Judging from the other comments, I'm not alone.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
(?<=\w\d)[; ](?=\d\w)
```

It will match ; or space preceded by a letter then a digit, then followed by a digit and a letter.

Edit: taking into account , and ;space and possible new line characters

```
(?<=[\w,]\d)[; ]+[\r\n\f]*(?=\d\w)
```

Also you can use [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) for testing regular expressions

Comment: Its not splitting in Expresso.

Comment: If we have new line char after space or (;) i.e. S. MOORE1 \r\n1Pathology,

Comment: Yeah its working , but again not working for this case : M. SASSOÈ-POGNETTO1; \r\n1Dept Anatomy

Comment: And with this also : MCCARTHY4,2,5 \r\n1Pharmacol.,

Comment: You should specify these cases in your question. You're adding , as a valid char and saying ; AND space: `(?<=[\w,]\d)[; ]+\r?\n?(?=\d\w)`

Comment: Sorry Laurence , As I am getting these cases in between.

Comment: Sometimes it contains  MCCARTHY5 \r\n\r\n\f\r\n1Address also.

Comment: At this point you might need to remove all line feed characters from your original string. You could try `(?<=[\w,]\d)[; ]+[\r\n\f]*(?=\d\w)` but I cannot test that right now.

Comment: Thanks , I will test and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
(.*)S. MOORE1;{0,1}(.*)
```

Catches 2 Groups before and after "S. MOORE1"

Comment: Thanks for the answer but S. MOORE1 is not there in every name-address combination.

Answer (score 0):

I have read your description many times, but I don't find it clear.

My best guess what you need is breaking the line before a word starting with '1' and continuing with capital letter as second character, which is as simple as:

```
1[A-Z]
```

Comment: More specifically split the string on pattern "digits followed by space or semicolon followed by digit" . Could you help me now?